# get the price of the first transaction and last transaction

Tags: sql-server, database

the question is about getting the price of the first transaction and last transaction of company in in each day,i can get the prices in this code

```
select t.date,t.PriceofShare as 'opening price'
from Trans t, Session s,Orders o
where s.date=t.Sdate
and t.Sdate=o.Sdate
and o.Sdate=s.date
and o.SID='MSFT'
```

returning this

```
date               opening price 
16:00:00.0000000    4000000.00
09:00:00.0000000    300000.00
```

but i don't know how to get the first one as opening price and last one as last price i tried

```
select t.date,t.PriceofShare as 'opening price'
from Trans t, Session s,Orders o
where s.date=t.Sdate
and t.Sdate=o.Sdate
and o.Sdate=s.date
and o.SID='MSFT'
and t.date=(select Min(date)
from Trans)
union
select t.date,t.PriceofShare as 'closing price'
from Trans t, Session s,Orders o
where s.date=t.Sdate
and t.Sdate=o.Sdate
and o.Sdate=s.date
and o.SID='MSFT'
and t.date=(select Max(date)
from Trans)
```

the result was

```
date               opening price  
16:00:00.0000000    4000000.00
```

please help
could my ER be wrong can i post my ER?

Comment: don't use old joins

Comment: Show full table schemas and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how you want the show the opening and closing price, but this should give you an idea..

```
SELECT *
FROM   Session s
       INNER JOIN Orders o
               ON o.Sdate = s.date
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 t.PriceofShare, t.date
                    FROM   Trans t
                    WHERE  s.date = t.Sdate
                           AND t.Sdate = o.Sdate
                    ORDER  BY t.date) o (OpeningPrice, OpeningPriceDate)
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 t.PriceofShare, t.date
                    FROM   Trans t
                    WHERE  s.date = t.Sdate
                           AND t.Sdate = o.Sdate
                    ORDER  BY t.date DESC) c (ClosingPrice, ClosingPriceDate)
WHERE  o.SID = 'MSFT'
```

Start using `INNER JOIN` syntax to join the table instead of old style comma separated join. Here is a good article about this [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: :) after seeing this i think the teacher gave me a project that the 2nd year student should get, he never taught us about these but i'll try it

Comment: @Samerthestalker - Am not very sure about the requirement.. may be I over complicated it.. If possible add sample data and expected result

Comment: weird got error o has more columns than were specified in the column list

Comment: same :) , i think he asked for this query by mistake no way i can know it with what i know now

Comment: @Samerthestalker - Oh I see.. Just lookup for `Cross Apply` isn't a hard concept..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need session?
Work with this.

```
select * 
from ( select t.date, t.PriceofShare as 'price'
            , row_number() over (partition by CONVERT(date, t.Sdate) order by t.date desc) as open  
            , row_number() over (partition by CONVERT(date, t.Sdate) order by t.date asc)  as close 
         from Trans t  
         join Orders o
           on o.Sdate = t.Sdate
          and o.SID   = 'MSFT'  
) tt
where tt.open = 1 or tt.close = 1 
order by t.date
```

Comment: session determine the day and i need the first transaction and last transaction in each day of the company MSFT

Comment: @Samerthestalker Just what to you need from the session table?  Did you test this solution?

Comment: i need the date from the session table,yes got error incorrect syntax near keyword 'join'

Comment: WHY do you need the date from the session table?  Where is it used?  It is just t.Sdate that you already have.  Apply yourself - remove the comma.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot that i need to put the market name in each date cause a session open each day in a market so i need MID from Session too

Comment: Did you you also forget to check the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this question. You can use windows function first_value and last_value.

```
select 
first_value(PriceofShare) over(order by t.date) as first_value,
last_value(PriceofShare) over(order by t.date) as last_value
from Trans t, Session s,Orders o
where s.date=t.Sdate
and t.Sdate=o.Sdate
and o.Sdate=s.date
and o.SID='MSFT'
```